# Why doesn't `map` work on an array create with `new Array(x)`?

Tags: javascript

I assumed these would be equal:

```
new Array(1).fill(0); // [0]

new Array(1).map(x => 0); // [undefined]
```

Why doesn't `map` work in the second case?

Comment: Because `new Array(1)` is an array with _one empty index_. The array has a length of 1 but it doesn’t have the property `0`, so there’s nothing to iterate over.

Comment: It does work. It just doesn't do what you think it does, because `map` skips "holes".

Comment: You can refer polyfill on following post [MDN - Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information